# Set a string to a letter inputted by a user

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing something in python, and I don't understand why this section of code isn't working.

```
m = 1
f = 0
gender_choice = False

while gender_choice == False:
    gender = input('Are you male or female? Type m for male or f for female. ')
    if gender == m or gender == f:
    print
    gender_choice = True
else:
    print
    print "Hey, this is a text based game. Read and follow bro."

print gender
```

I think I understand that there is an issue with setting a string to "m" or "f", but unless I change raw_input to input, the loop will continue. Also, as is currently written, if the user enters anything other than a number, m, or f, I will get an error that the string is undefined, for example, if they enter "y".

Comment: you are comparing strings and numbers

Comment: As currently written, you have an `IndentationError` since the line after your `if` statement is not indented.

Comment: `m` is a variable (in your code, it's equal to `1`), and `'m'` is a string you are asking the user to enter, which you are assigning the name `gender`. If the user enters `m` as their answer, your if statement is `if 'm' == 1` which is of course never going to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of check your indentation!

This is how I would think that you'd like it to look:

```
m = 1
f = 0
gender_choice = False

while gender_choice == False:
    gender = input('Are you male or female? Type m for male or f for female. ')
    if gender == m or gender == f:
        print
        gender_choice = True
    else:
        print
        print "Hey, this is a text based game. Read and follow bro."

print gender
```

Then your else statement will only get executed when your if statement gets evaluated as False, which is always at the moment since it evaluates whether gender == 1 or gender == 0 which will only happen if your user does not "Read and follow bro." I do not know if you need the m and f variables later in your code but I'm going to assume that you do, so what I'd do is this:

```
gender_choice = False

while gender_choice == False:
    gender = raw_input('Are you male or female? Type m for male or f for female. ')
    if gender == "m":
        print
        gender_bool = 1
        gender_choice = True
    elif gender == "f":
        print
        gender_bool = 0
        gender_choice = True
    else:
        print "\nHey, this is a text based game. Read and follow bro.\n"

print gender
```

That way your logic works and the m and f variable has been put into one variable (gender_bool) that can be evaluated in later logic, the if statements evaluates something that makes more sense (imho) and you use raw_input so that you can enter anything in there without raising errors (and I added some \n (linebreaks) to please my OCD :P).

Comment: It works exactly how I had imagined, thank-you. I don't quite understand what bool does however, and why I needed it. I commented it out for the time being, and the code functions the same without it.

Comment: @TylerDuncan I put in gender_bool in place of the leading m = 1 f = 0 vars in your original code thinking that you had them there for a reason... But you can use it later in your text game logic to see if the char is a male or a female.